# How to write Tests in ASP.NET Core app with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How should unit test look in ASP.NET Core app for controllers? And I have a database SQL Server and my app is connected with my app by EF Core. My views are `.cshtml` files and in `Index` method it depends on the data from db. For example it is one of my controllers (HomeController). Also I have services and models in my app and views. I don't know is it a right way to test services or controllers? And how?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // ...
    [Route("home")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var lst = _service.GetAll();
        return View(lst);
    }

    [Route("about")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

How to write a test for this? I know that this way is not correct but I don't know another...

```
[Test]
public async Task CheckHome_SendRequest_ShouldReturnOk() 
{
    // Arrange
    WebApplicationFactory<Startup> webHost = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
               .WithWebHostBuilder(_ => { });

    HttpClient httpClient = webHost.CreateClient();

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("home");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpResponse.StatusCode);
}
```

**Edit:** it can be other type of tests

Comment: The codes indacates you are trying with Integration test not Unit Test,which do you really want?

Comment: @ruikai-feng Any type, I just want to test my code

Comment: learn about DI
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection

Comment: @gingerbreadboy I didn't ask about DI, I know about it and I implemented this in my app, my app works fine but I asked about testing

Comment: righto, then it should be easy for you to mock out `_service` and then your test should be easy. Your question is vague at best. What behaviour of your app specifically are you trying to test?

Comment: Ruikai's question is right on the money, if you don't know which you want then you need to go and do some reading.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy don't be so arrogant. I tried to read, and this topic is not easy to me, I don't understand how to test ASP.NET Core app. That's why I asked here. If you don't want to help - better don't write me anything

Comment: stackoverflow is for specific questions and answers. Your question is either too broad or requires more clarity. Sorry if this sounds arrogant, kind regards.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy I'm new at StackOverflow and maybe my question is stupid for you.  So in this case don't care about my question, I will wait for the kind developer who will help me with advice.

Comment: What is the system under test in this case, is it the viewing of the model, is it the db service? A quick rule of thumb: If it's a sum of the two than it's an integration test, if it's a single thing than it's a unit-test

Comment: `unit`-test, as the name says, is for testing parts of your code. The smaller, the better. Integration tests are a different story. `I just want to test my code` is neither a good approach, nor a helpful hint, how we can help you. Some examples (i guess you already found them yourself): [Test controller logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0), [repo tests](https://code-maze.com/testing-repository-pattern-entity-framework/), [integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0), etc.

Comment: And dont forget about e2e-tests - we just don't know what you want and explaining all of them is a lit much here and already answered multiple times. Btw, i did not read any arrogance anywhere, just confusion ...

Comment: Take a look at this piece of MSDN documentation about testing controllers in asp.net-core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: To improve your questions, you could read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a good start. In short: ask one question and show your code, that is not working as expected. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try to figure it out and I will update my question if I will still be confused

Comment: The question is probably "how to test controllers", which is a common one, and not with an obvious solution on a surface.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so if I'm getting this correctly, the system under test here is the Controller.

So, first thing (that you are already doing) would be to have a decent DI and inject controller's dependencies into the Controller, for example, via contstructor.

Then, you would need to build your DI container and your mocking mechanism such that the `Controller` instance would be instantiated with mocked dependencies.

Then, you simply ask your DI to give you said instance and make a direct call to its method (or methods) that you are testing.

And then you `Assert` on either outcome of the controller's method's result, or what methods on the injected mocked dependencies the controller called, or both.

P.S. So, there is no need for `HttpClient`. By using `HttpClient` and making an actual web request you test (and also make your invoke dependable upon) lots of unneccesary stuff, like the network layer of the operation system, pipeline of the asp.net framework, and so on. So, the simpler — the better, is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use an inmemory database using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory nuget package.

My unit test setup looks like this:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("MyInMemoryTestDb")
        .Options;
    _db = new MyContext(options); //the ef core db context
    _service = new ServiceIWantToTest(_db);
    MockData(); //this adds some testable data to _db using regular EF Core methods
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    _db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a base class for initializing your testserver

```
public abstract class TestBase : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _databaseInitialized;
        
        private HttpClient? _client;

        private TestServer TestServer { get; }

        public TestBase(Action<IServiceCollection>? testServicesConfiguration = null)
        {
            // create a test server instance
            TestServer = CreateServer(testServicesConfiguration ?? (s => { }));
        }
        
        public static TestServer CreateServer(Action<IServiceCollection> testServicesConfiguration)
        {
            var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(cb =>
                                           {
                                               cb.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                                   .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                                           })
                .ConfigureTestServices(testServicesConfiguration)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, builder) =>
                                           {
                                               builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true);
                                           });

            return new TestServer(hostBuilder);
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri) =>
            await GetClient().GetAsync(requestUri);

        private HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            // singleton
            return TestServer.CreateClient();
        }
    }
```

And create a new inherit class from testBase for the test sets:

```
public class GetScenarioIT : TestBase
{
    protected virtual string TestEndpoint() => "admin/home";

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_and_response_ok_status_code()
    {
        // Act
        var response = await GetAsync(TestEndpoint());

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```